# Вывод данных авторизированного пользователя

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте сделал авторизацию пользователя в программе через бд по логину и паролю.Хотелось чтобы после входа.Выводились данные авторизованного пользователя.Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как можно это реализовать.
Вот код авторизации:

```
   using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Desktop\база\Питание.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count (1) From Регистрация where Логин=@login and Пароль=@Pass", con)) 
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pass", textBox2.Text);


                var accountsCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();


                if (accountsCount==1)
                {
                    Form5 a = new Form5();
                    a.label1.Text = accountsCount.ToString();
                    a.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Неверные данные");
                }

            }



        }
```

Comment: `textBox1.Text` или какая-то другая информация имеется ввиду? Также надеюсь Вы понимаете, что эта «авторизация» не спасет от человека, который подключится к файлу напрямую (например, через management studio) и прочитает все логины и пароли.

Comment: У меня есть таблица в sql где есть столбцы  с названием Имя, Логин, Пароль,Рост , Вес и мне нужно чтобы авторизованный пользователь после входа видел свои данные которые он ввёл при регистрации.

Comment: Ну Вы же написали запрос к таблице `Регистрация`. В чем проблема написать такой же запрос к таблице, скажем `Пользователи`? Попробуйте описать подробнее с чем именно возникли сложности, чтобы отвечающие знали на чем сконцентрировать свое внимание.

Comment: Ну вот с этой таблицы регистрация нужно вывести полностью все данные этого зарегистрированного пользователя.Например у меня есть пользователь с логином 123 и паролем 123 и у него же есть еще данные такие как  пол рост вес.При авторизации я ввожу логин 123 и пароль 123 и при успешном входе. На следующей форме мне высвечивается пол,рост и вес пользователя который вошел под логином 123 и паролем 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так же как и с «авторизацией», с помощью [`SqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) выполняем запрос к таблице, проставляя список нужных столбцов:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select пол, рост, вес From Регистрация where Логин=@login and Пароль=@Pass", con))
{
```

Чтобы прочитать результаты используем метод [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx), который возвращает объект [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx). Этот объект содержит методы по чтению набора данных.

В документации к методу есть пример использования:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
```

К столбцам можно обращаться по порядку в запросе (`reader[1]`, `reader[2]`) так и по именам (`reader["пол"], reader["рост"]`, и т.д.). Поэкспериментируйте с запросом и чтением результатов и выберите удобный способ.

З.Ы. Стоит заметить что такая «авторизация» имеет смысл только для Вашего приложения и не защищает от прямого доступа к файлу БД. Для защиты данных устанавливайте сервер и настраивайте встроенную авторизацию. И не храните пароли в открытом виде.

Comment: Спасибо,все получилось.Всего вам самого хорошего))

Comment: @EgorPyshnov Пожалуйста! Если проблема решена, то можете отметить вопрос как решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers